# What are the causes of Reaction Wheel Failures/Anomalies?

Tags: attitude, reference-request, engineering, failure, reaction-wheel

What are the mechanisms of [reaction wheel anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel#Failures_and_replacement)? Are there any [fish bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishikawa_diagram) or [fault tree analyses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_tree_analysis) on these issues?

Comment: [This question](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/why-do-reaction-wheels-fail-so-frequently) has most of your answers, yet no fault tree analysis. I'm still voting to close as a duplicate, because if anyone has that data it can be added there. BTW I found this answer as *the first hit* Googling for 'reaction wheel failures'. Maybe you should do some homework before asking a question?

Comment: I've added a new response on a specific failure mode, bearing cage instability, to the other question, http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/why-do-reaction-wheels-fail-so-frequently/13768#13768, to keep those answers together.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to presume that a [related question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/why-do-reaction-wheels-fail-so-frequently) linked in the comments answers the first part of the question and will focus on the latter part of it as a reference request follow-up to the linked one. Since no specific mission's methodology was inquired about, here are some arbitrarily selected publications on the topic of fault detection and management:

Example:

- [A Systematic Risk Management Approach Employed on the CloudSat Project](https://www.trylam.com/files/2001IEEE_A_Systematic_Risk_Management_Approach_Employed_on_the_CloudSat_Project.pdf), R. R. Basilio et al., Jet Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology, California, 2000 (PDF)

General references:

- [A Fault-Tree Approach for Identifying Causes of Actuator Failure in Attitude Control Subsystems of Space Vehicles](https://spectrum.library.concordia.ca/id/eprint/8103/1/MQ94691.pdf), A. Barua, Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Concordia University Montreal, Canada, 2004 (PDF)
- [A novel fault-tree approach for identifying potential causes of satellite reaction wheel failure](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1507339), A. Barua et al., Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Concordia University Montreal, Canada, 2005
- [Goal-Function Tree Modeling for Systems Engineering and Fault Management](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140002994.pdf), S. B. Johnson et al., Jacobs ESSSA Group, American Institute of Aeronautics and Astronautics, 2014 (PDF)
- [Innovative Fault Detection, Isolation and Recovery Strategies On-Board Spacecraft: State of the Art and Research Challenges](https://www.dglr.de/publikationen/2013/281268.pdf), A. Wander & R. Förstner, Bundeswehr University Munich, Institute of Space Technology and Space Applications, Neubiberg, Germany, 2012 (PDF)
- [Root Cause Investigation Best Practices Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20180417054203/http://www.aerospace.org:80/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/TOR-2014-02202-Root-Cause-Investigation-Best-Practices-Guide.pdf), R. J. Duphily, Acquisition Risk and Reliability Engineering Department, National Reconnaissance Office, 2014 (PDF)
- [Effective Fault Management Guidelines](https://web.archive.org/web/20150708181400/http://www.aerospace.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/TOR-20098591-14-Effective-Fault-Management-Guidelines.pdf), S. L. Hogan, Digital and Integrated Circuit Electronics Department, Air Force Space Command, El Segundo, California, 2009 (PDF)

Comment: Excellent documents. I'll review these documents immediately...Thanks and best regards.......